# Add custom plist to a project on Appcelerator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

One of the third party frameworks we use on our projects needs a plist file to be added to Xcode, it provides some configurations keys for that framework. Of course we can use Hyperloop to integrate the framework, but how doI add this plist file to the project in the way that it is compiled just as a native on and the framework can found it on the app to work?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your tiapp.xml you have a  section.
As far as I understood, this is where you should put your configurations into, because its content is given to xcode as it's plist contents.

Maybe you take a look into: 
[Appcelerator Reference](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-src-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-plist)

> You can include a custom Info.plist file in the top-level directory of
>   your Titanium project, but these value are overwritten by the settings
>   in the  section of the tiapp.xml file.

Hope this helps you.

Greetings Dom

Comment: First of all, Thanks for the reply. Add to the  tiapp.xml does not work in this case because the framework looks for the specific plist file in the bundle, not as keys on the main plist the  tiapp.xml will add to. So it needs to be a new asset in the bundle that the framework look for on the documents for the app and  tiapp.xml unfortunatelly does not help on this case :-( Any other options? If we can add modules, or other assets, maybe there is a way to add the plist as well or a another configuration file like a xml or json

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't help you. Could you specify the framework? May be I can take a look into it to figure out what exactly is needed.